# Можно ли задать расположение элементов в svg, используя css grid

Tags: css, svg, css-grid

Я решаю задачу по генерации svg изображений, при этом важно расположить правильным образом элементы (под изображения) в общем изображнии. Очень удобно размещать изображения с помощью css grid, но к сожалению, не получается использовать css grid для подэлеметов svg. По крайне мере, не получается при простом переносе css свойства.

Так все таки можно как то исопльзовать css grid для svg, или же это просто не реализовано?

Пример реализации grid css: https://jsfiddle.net/Nic34/yh61nxru/

```css
#wrapp {
  display: grid;
  grid: "w1 w2" "w1 w3";
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background: burlywood;
  background: burlywood;
  border: 10px solid burlywood;  
}

#wrapp div {
  background: bisque;
}

#w1 { grid-area: w1; }
#w2 { grid-area: w2; }
#w3 { grid-area: w3; }
```

```html
<div id=wrapp>
  <div id='w1'>1</div>
  <div id='w2'>2</div>
  <div id='w3'>3</div>
</div>
```

Пример для svg: https://jsfiddle.net/Nic34/adm0ogy9/

```css
#wrapp {
  display: grid;
  grid: "w1 w2" "w1 w3";
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background: burlywood;
  background: burlywood;
  border: 10px solid burlywood;  
}

#wrapp div {
  background: bisque;
}

#w1 { grid-area: w1; }
#w2 { grid-area: w2; }
#w3 { grid-area: w3; }
```

```html
<svg id=wrapp viewBox="0, 0, 100, 100">
  <g id='w1'>1</g>
  <g id='w2'>2</g>
  <g id='w3'>3</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Я правильно вас понял, что в grid css будут в каждом прямоугольнике растровые изображения, и в каждом прямоугольнике, также под растровым изображением должен  быть svg элемент, например иконка, кнопка svg

Comment: Тут важно именно расположение элементов, и не важно, что именно это за элемент - изображение ли, иконка ли или же элемент svg. Главное, чтобы элементы можно было разместить не задавая точные координаты (как это обычно делают для рисования svg).

Comment: ещё раз уточню, растровая картинка и svg элемент должен быть в одной ячейке grid? Допустим растровая картинка занимает у вас всю ячейку grid, как фон, а svg изображение должно быть сверху картинки? или в той же ячейке, под картинкой внизу?

Comment: В разных чейках. Каждый элемент задается в отдельной ячейке. Но ячейки могут иметь разные размеры и просто таблицей это не решить, или решение будет слишком громодким.

Comment: то есть одна ячейка для растровой картинки, другая ячейка ниже картинки для svg?

Comment: Именно так, все верно